# Is it possible to count the number of app installs derived from my website?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, google-analytics

I have a specific website which drives traffic to my app page in Google Play/Apple App Store.

The end goal is to accurately know how many installs (or first-time app activations) came from that site.

I'm guessing I need some method to report the count event after the initial app activation in which I can see if the user visited the site or not. 
Does Google Analytics has this ability? Or do I actually need to make my own ip-addresses DB in the site and compare it with the user's ip in the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can find where(Market) the app is installed from using  `getInstallerPackageName`

> Retrieve the package name of the application that installed a package. This identifies which market the package came from.

I am afraid you cannot find "whether the app was installed, after it was redirected from your site". But you can find how many redirects where made from your site by putting a counter on your website for each re-direction.

**You can find it by enabling the user to download the app from your site and for that app to have a different signature than the one from the market. You can then compare the signature in your app** 
Then compare it using

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();

PackageInfo appInfo = manager.getPackageInfo(
        YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
boolean shouldUseTestServer = 
        appInfo.signatures[0].toCharsString().equals(YOUR_SITE_APP_SIGNATURE);
```

Comment: Meaning I will give the option to download the APK directly from the site. which is not a viable solution for iOS.